# Derivatives of a meromorphic function determined by principal part of Laurent series at singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(x)$ be a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{P}^1$ with poles at $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k 
> \in \mathbb{P}^1$ (and holomorphic everywhere else). Let $u \in \mathbb{P}^1$ such that $u \neq a_i$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$. Give an expression for $f^{(n)}(u)$ involving $x_i^m=\mathrm{res}_{z=a_i}(z-a_i)^mf(z)$, where $\mathrm{res}_{z=a}g(z)$ is the residue of $g(z)$ at $z=a$.

*Attempt:* I thought first of all to use the Cauchy integral formula to write
$$f^{(n)}(u) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-u)^{n+1}}dz.$$
Where $\gamma$ is a small counterclockwise circle around $z=u$, not containing any of the $a_i$'s.

Now, I thought I could use the residue theorem and the fact that all the singularities are contained on the "outside" of this path:
$$f^{(n)}(u) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{(z-u)^{n+1}}dz = -n!\sum_{i=1}^k \mathrm{res}_{z=a_i} \frac{f(z)}{(z-u)^{n+1}}.$$
But I don't know how to relate this last part to the residues I actually want (i.e. the $x_i^m$).

EDIT: I think I know how to proceed. To calculate $\mathrm{res}_{z=a_i}\frac{f(z)}{(z-u)^{n+1}}$ we note that the Laurent series of $f(z)$ at $z=a_i$ is $f(z)=\sum_{m=-e_i}^\infty x_i^{m+1} (z-a_i)^m$ where $e_i$ is the order of the pole at $a_i$. We can also explicitly calculate the Taylor series of $(z-u)^{-n-1}$:
$$\frac{1}{(z-u)^{n+1}} = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(m+n)!}{m!(u-a_i)^{m+n+1}}(z-a_i)^m.$$
By multiplying these together we can see that the residue will be
$$\mathrm{res}_{z=a_i}\frac{f(z)}{(z-u)^{n+1}} = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{m=1}^{e_i} \frac{(m+n-1)!}{(m-1)!(u-a_i)^{m+n}}x_i^{1-m}$$
Putting this expression into the above formula gives the desired expression.

This actually leaves me confused now. Since, to me, this is saying a meromorphic function is determined by the principal parts of its Laurent expansions at all of its poles, but this isn't true! On a compact Riemann surface, this only determines the function up to a scalar? I will ask create a new question to ask this.

Comment: For your last equation to be correct you have to include the residue at infinity, otherwise your equation is not true (e.g.: $f(z)=e^z, k=0, n=0$)

Comment: @Caffeine thanks! I intended for the question to imply that either $\infty$ is one of the $a_i$'s or is not a singular point. I'll edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: as for relating the residues that the $a_i$, if $h_1$ has a pole at $a$ and $h_2$ is holomorphic at $a$, then $$\mathrm{res}_{z=a} (h_1(z)h_2(z)) = h_2(a)\mathrm{res}_{z=a} h_1(z)$$

Comment: Thanks @PaulSinclair, but am I misinterpreting your comment? What about the example $a=0$, $h_1(z)=z^{-2}$ and $h_2(z) = z$? By your calculation, the residue should be $0$ but in fact the residue is $1$.